# Add class to next integer on click while removing from current jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wrapping the class; slideVisible to the first 3 blog articles displayed. This class removes the css property; display - none. I have added some indicators with the class; carousel-buttons, which also is based on the number of loops of sets of 3 blog posts. On click of these carousel-buttons I would like to remove the class slideVisible from the element which currently has it, and then add to the next element in the sequence.

I have used an index-related selector to demonstrate a way of creating this function, however this is not dynamic. How would I do this correctly?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var carosuelPost = jQuery(".post-slider-mango .post");

    jQuery('.post-slider-mango .fusion-posts-container').wrapAll('<div id="dog-slider"><div class="carousel-inner"></div></div>');

    for (var i = 0; i < carosuelPost.length; i += 3) {
        let activeClass = '';
        if(i == 0) activeClass = 'slideVisible';
        carosuelPost.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll('<div class="slideElements ' + activeClass + '"> </div>');
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < carosuelPost.length; i += 3) {
        if(i == 0) activeClass = 'slideVisible';
        jQuery(".post-slider-mango .fusion-posts-container").after('<a class="carousel-buttons"><li></li></a>');

        jQuery(".carousel-buttons:eq(0)").on("click", function() {
            jQuery(".slideElements").removeClass("slideVisible");
            jQuery(".slideElements:eq(0)").addClass("slideVisible");
        });

        jQuery(".carousel-buttons:eq(1)").on("click", function() {
            jQuery(".slideElements").removeClass("slideVisible");
            jQuery(".slideElements:eq(1)").addClass("slideVisible");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: could you explain your exact need , also with html and whole code here

Comment: @Spring, the HTML is created by a wordpress theme, it has so many classes and is messy of course. In an ideal world, I would just use a bootstrap carousel, but this wasn't possible, so I am trying to create a jquery carousel. So basically I would like the carousel-buttons to react like bootstrap carosuel indicators. Onclick remove the class from the active slide and add to the next in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

So it's hard to say because it depends on the element that has the `activeClass` class and the heirarchy. You can have the `.carousel-button` on click remove the class from its parent, or parent's parent.

You can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the closest ancestor with x class. So:

```
// Declare function that removes a given class from given element

// Set click event listener for .carousel-button elements
$('.carousel-button').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('div.slideVisible').removeClass('slideVisible');
});
```

Also to note, I would use a `<button>` element for the `carousel-button` so you do not then need to use the `e.preventDefault()` in the click event. If it is only to be used to run JavaScript via user interaction then you do not need to use an `<a>` tag.

See snippet for working example.

```js
// Set click event listener for .carousel-button elements
$('.carousel-button').click(function(){
 const next = $(this).closest('div.slideVisible').next().is('.slide');
if (next) {
return $(this).closest('div.slideVisible').removeClass('slideVisible').next().addClass('slideVisible');
} else {
  return $(this).closest('div.slideVisible').removeClass('slideVisible').prev().addClass('slideVisible');
}

});
```

```css
.slide {
  display:none;
  padding:2rem;
  text-align:center;
background:orange;
}
.slide2 {
background:yellow;
}

.slideVisible {
  display:block;
}

.carousel-button {
  padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slide slide1 slideVisible">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="carousel-button">Hide Me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide slide2">
  <div class="buttons">
    <p>This is slide 2</p>
    <button class="carousel-button">Hide Me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** This answer assumes that you're trying to remove the class from a parent of the button you're clicking. If you need to get it from the sibling before or after you can use [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) after calling the .closest() method:

```
$(this).closest('div.slideVisible').prev().removeClass('slideVisible');
```

Comment: I think if there is a lot of carousel elements this could get confusing, and furthermore, the buttons are not the children (in this case, and yea i didn't include html so it is my fault here.) I was thinking more of some sort onclick if if statement like if slideElements have class, remove active class. Or maybe add the interager to each button and slide element. So button-1 onclick equals slide one visible and all else hidden.

Comment: I have added this to the second for loop, it doesn't work, but I guess this is a general idea.  

  jQuery(".carousel-buttons:nth-child("+ i +")").on("click", function() {
   jQuery(".slideElements").removeClass("slideVisible");
            jQuery(".slideElements:nth-child("+ i +")").addClass("slideVisible");
       });

Comment: It's the general idea, yeah. It's hard to say really without seeing the HTML when it's rendered. If you can screen shot the elements in dev tools or something and upload that'd help.

If all 3 posts are inside of the slideVisible container, and the button to hide it is, then you can use the code I've provided.

I've edited my code as well to decipher whether there's a next sibling or not. If there is, it will remove the class from the current container and add the class to the next sibling .slide. If there's not, it will remove class from current and add class to previous sibling .slide

Comment: If you copy the code into somewhere like codepen and then add more .slide containers with buttons in them you'll be able to see how it's working. Then should be able to apply this logic to what you need to do.

Comment: Hey joe, I created a fiddle, there is a lot of missing css and so much avada and wordpress classes. Its quite hard to read through, but here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/yxosap2r/

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Here you go, I removed a lot of the HTML just so we are down to the elements in question. It looks like the wrapAll was adding an extra .slideElements, as this class already exists around the .item, unless that's what you're doing before rendering. Anyway the code works: jsfiddle.net/8wbut0o6/1